# Git Repository cloned, Couldn't make few folders

Tags: git, clone

I'm trying to clone a GIT repository, it says it has been cloned but cant make few folders stating permission denied. can anyone help me with that ?

check the screenshot here

http://wizcrust.com/git/git_error.jpg

Comment: what are the permissions to the directory you are working in?

Comment: In the future, you should paste the text of the error, not a screenshot (where possible). It reduces the dependency on external sites and ensures your question will be available for generations to come.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the user account running git does'nt have permission to create directories.

Could you change the permission of the directory you are trying to clone into?

Unless its

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

or something of the like, it should be a simple directory permission issue.

Try changing the permission of the destination directory with

`Chmod -Rf 755 directoryname`